# Apex Oracle - Multiple Dynamic Actions

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a PL/SQL code block executed within a Dynamic action for a button. It works, but whenever i add a Client-side Condition --> JavaScript Expression to show a success message or submit the page, it doesn't work.

Is it possible to integrate JavaScript into PL/SQL code to submit the page?
I'm using apex 5.1

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic action can have more than one *action*; you use a PL/SQL code, so - add yet another, which will Submit the page.

Comment: i've tried redirecting using PL SQL but it shows this error :Ajax call returned server error ORA-20876: Stop APEX Engine for Execute PL/SQL Code.

Comment: Redirecting? That's not what I said; literally, add a new True action which Submits the page.